# Managing fragments

Tags: android, optimization, android-fragments

I'm now creating a simple pageviewer-supported application, where you can switch thru fragments horizontally. For my application I want to use the same background for all of the fragments, the only difference between fragments would be the text. I've currently made a few fragments and the application is already overly-solicitating, it is taking a lot of space and using a lot of memory. I want to optimize the application in some way so the space and memory needed for running it to be minimized. Here is my MainActivity's code: (I'm creating a class and a different layout for each fragment as I'm not currently familiarized with any other way of doing so) --Edit: I've forgot to say, at the moment I have only 7 fragments but for my application I need like 400-500 fragments so a optimization is a must.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }        
    });

}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {Fragment f = null;
    switch(position){
    case 0:
    {
    f = new DummySectionFragment();//YourFragment
    // set arguments here, if required
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    f.setArguments(args);
    break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        f = new Fragment2();//YourFragment
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        f = new Fragment3();//YourFragment
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        f = new Fragment4();//YourFragment
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        f = new Fragment5();//YourFragment
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        f = new Fragment6();//YourFragment
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
    }
    case 6:
    {
        f = new Fragment7();//YourFragment
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
    }

    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("not this many fragments: " + position);
    }


    return f;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 7;
    }


}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }


}  public static class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public Fragment2() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}  public static class Fragment3 extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public Fragment3() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}  public static class Fragment4 extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public Fragment4() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment4, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}  public static class Fragment5 extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public Fragment5() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment5, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    } }  
    public static class Fragment6 extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public Fragment6() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment6, container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }   } 
        public static class Fragment7 extends Fragment {
            /**
             * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
             * fragment.
             */
            public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

            public Fragment7() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment7, container, false);
                TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView;    }


}
}
```

Comment: How many Fragments do you have in total?

Comment: at the moment I have 7 fragments but for my application I want to have 400-500.

Comment: ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); - you can set the number of pages that will be kept in memory.

Comment: Ohhh, right ! Thank you ! As for the fragments themselves, there is any other easier way to create them? I mean, by not having a different class for each of them?

Comment: To start with, all of your fragments are the exact same code and the args are passed in to them. You only would need one Fragment class and just pass in different args.

Answer (score 0):

> To manage the fragments in your activity, you need to use
>   FragmentManager. To get it, call getFragmentManager() from your
>   activity.
>
> Some things that you can do with FragmentManager include:
>
> ```
> Get fragments that exist in the activity, with findFragmentById() (for fragments that provide a UI in the activity layout) or
> ```
>
> findFragmentByTag() (for fragments that do or don't provide a UI).
>       Pop fragments off the back stack, with popBackStack() (simulating a Back command by the user).
>       Register a listener for changes to the back stack, with addOnBackStackChangedListener().